# Android: get as a static String a value from a URL

Tags: android

URL = http://troyka.esy.es/numberofrows.php

if you put that in your browser you'l get a number (currently it's 9)

I'm trying to pull that number to my android app and display it on a textview

I've tried this method but it shows me nothing on the emulator
internet and network permission are set on manifest

textview id = "textView"

What am I doing wrong?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static String ans;
    private TextView T1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        T1 = new TextView(this);

        T1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        T1.setText(ans);

    }
    public String getDATA() throws IOException {
        String fullString = "";
        URL url = new URL("http://troyka.esy.es/numberofrows.php");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            fullString += line;
        }
        reader.close();
        return fullString;
    }
    public void setAns() throws IOException {
        ans = getDATA();
    }
}
```

Comment: You are not calling the getDATA method?

Comment: tried returning a string and calling it on the settext also didnt work

Comment: i'll edit my code with the basic implementing

Comment: I don't see where you actually call the getDATA() method; so the value of ans is empty

Comment: code is editted still aint workin :/

Comment: You have to call setAns() method after T1 = (TextView) findVi....

Comment: ok , I called it on onCreate, the compiler wanted a try catch, and application has crashed :/

Comment: You cannot make a Network operation (http request) on the main thread, so move the code in my answer (where you do the GET request) to an AsyncTask

Comment: I;m pretty new to android , can you show me the MainActivity and the new class , getting hard time implementing all of this

Comment: Give me a few minutes please!

Comment: Sure man, thanks in advance!

Comment: I have written  a more detailed answer for you; please let me know if you need further help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this answer please:

First, create an AsyncTask class like this to do the actual HTTP request for you outside the android main thread:

```
public class FetchColumnAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> 
{
    private Context mContext;

    public FetchColumnAsync( Context ctx){
       this.mContext = ctx; 
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
       String fullString = "";
       try{

          URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
          BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
          String line;
          while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             fullString += line;
          }
          reader.close();
        }catch(Exception e ){
           e.getMessage();
        }

        return fullString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String value){
       try{
          ((OnValueFetchedListener) mContext).onValueFetched(value);
       }catch(ClassCastException e){}
    }

    public interface OnValueFetchedListener{
        void onValueFetched(String columns);
    }

}
```

Then in your activity class, implement the above interface like this;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements FetchColumnAsync.OnValueFetchedListener{
   public static String ans;
   private TextView T1;

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       T1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

       //missing piece of code here
       new FetchColumnAsync(this).execute("http://troyka.esy.es/numberofrows.php");

   }

   @Override
   public void onValueFetched(String value){
      T1.setText(value);
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much , made another android beginner's day :)

Comment: It worked , and that number 9 means a lot mate, thanks again!

Comment: Hey man, can you tell me please, how can I get the string from the php fetch right into a string variable on MainActivity?

Comment: You see, it will be tricky to do so because you are using an AsyncTask which works outside the main thread. You are basically 'asking' another 'guy' to go somewhere and fetch you something and just notify you when he gets back; so you don't know when he gets back as long as he does.

Comment: is there any chance you can take a look over my other stackoverflow question, that question is the reason for all of this :P

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32530442/android-refresh-listview-every-minute?noredirect=1#comment52919262_32530442