# Android: Refresh ListView every minute

Tags: android

I've been reading all day threads regarding this issue I came up with a strategy but can't make it work

I have a listview fetching json data from a sql server
this listview already has a on swipe refresh function

I need this listview to refresh automatically only when new row was inserted in the data base.

So I wrote a php file fetching number of rows and echoing it witha  3 second refresh (on the php itself) so every time I enter the php file I get the realtime row numbers of my table.

I'm trying to build a function inside my MainActivity:

```
int OldNumberOfRows = data from the php file
while(true){
int newNumberOfRows = fetch data again using that php
if(both arent equal) execute refresh command.
}
```

Note: I got no idea how to extract the string from my asynctask to start manipulating my code with it.

That's it in general, Iv'e added the main activity , the "outer class" (FetchNumRowAsync) calling that php the swipe class and the php itself

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private String URL = "http://troyka.esy.es/troyka/orders.php";


    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefreshLayout;
    private ListView listView;
    private SwipeListAdapter adapter;
    private List<Order> orderList;

    // initially offset will be 0, later will be updated while parsing the json
    private int offSet = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new FetchRowNumAsync(this).execute("http://troyka.esy.es/numberofrows.php");

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        //RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout_description = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(50,10);

        //Rl.setLayoutParams(layout_description);

        swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);

        orderList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new SwipeListAdapter(this, orderList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        /**
         * Showing Swipe Refresh animation on activity create
         * As animation won't start on onCreate, post runnable is used
         */
        swipeRefreshLayout.post(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

                                        fetchOrders();
                                    }
                                }
        );

    }

    /**
     * This method is called when swipe refresh is pulled down
     */


    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        fetchOrders();
    }

    /**
     * Fetching movies json by making http call
     */
    private void fetchOrders() {

        // showing refresh animation before making http call
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        // appending offset to url
        String url = URL + offSet;

        // Volley's json array request object
        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

                        if (response.length() > 0) {

                            // looping through json and adding to order list
                            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject orderObj = response.getJSONObject(i);

                                    int rank = orderObj.getInt("rank");
                                    String title = orderObj.getString("title");

                                    Order m = new Order(rank, title);

                                    orderList.add(0, m);

                                    // updating offset value to highest value
                                    if (rank >= offSet)
                                        offSet = rank;

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "JSON Parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }

                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }

                        // stopping swipe refresh
                        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Server Error: " + error.getMessage());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                // stopping swipe refresh
                swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }

}
```

FetchRowNumAsync:

```
public class FetchRowNumAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>  {

    private Context mContext;

    public FetchRowNumAsync(Context ctx){
        this.mContext = ctx;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        String fullString = "";
        try{
            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                fullString += line;
            }
            reader.close();
        }catch(Exception e ){
            e.getMessage();
        }
        return fullString;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String value){
        try{
            ((OnValueFetchedListener) mContext).onValueFetched(value);
        }catch(ClassCastException e){}
    }

    public interface OnValueFetchedListener{
        void onValueFetched(String columns);
    }

}
```

SwipeListAdapter:

```
   public class SwipeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private List<Order> orderList;
        private String[] bgColors;

        public SwipeListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Order> orderList) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.orderList = orderList;
            bgColors = activity.getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_serial_bg);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return orderList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int location) {
            return orderList.get(location);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (inflater == null)
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            TextView serial = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.serial);
            TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);

            serial.setText(String.valueOf(orderList.get(position).id));
            title.setText(orderList.get(position).title);

            String color = bgColors[position % bgColors.length];
            serial.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));

            return convertView;
        }

}
```

PHP

```
<?php
header("refresh: 3;");

$mysqli = new mysqli("irrelevant","irrelevant","irrelevant","irrelevant");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orders";
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);

echo ($rows[0]);   

$result->close();

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: you can have a creation date in you database, so that you can query for only newer items.

Comment: I have a timestamp triggered every time a row is inserted, but its off topic mate

Comment: not really. If you use that, you'll receive only newer items, so you only have to insert whatever you receive from your server into your list.

Comment: but if the question is only about how to schedule a refresh in a given amount of time, a trivial `new Handler().postDelayed()` will do

Comment: See, I need to know when a new row was inserted to notify the user with a "vibration" or a sound,

Comment: if its impossible I also need to know :/

Comment: yeah, which would be easier if your service only returns the newer items, since then you can notify the user whenever you receive more than 0 item, and there is no need to compare anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

- Create an endpoint in your server like the following:

  ```
  //http://somesite.com/api/data/pull/check
  ```
- Then, you can easily check this endpoint that returns some value like **true** or **false** depending on whether there is new data inserted into the db.
- From the result you receive, you can then decide on whether to refresh your data on the phone by making another HTTP request or not. You always want to avoid making unnecessary requests to the server - remember users spend money every time they use their data plan (service).
- I, like in the comments above, recommend having a column with a timestamp that you can check so that you only get the newly added data instead of everything!

I hope this gives you a simple idea on how to approach this issue! Good luck!

Comment: What I understand is my general approach was wrong, I would like to know your opinion about what I got to so far, php file that simple selects all rows from table, parses it to json and android listview fetches that..                       clearly from reading the replies here I understand that is my general mistake, question is how to "fetch" only new data by php?

Comment: Probably just a simple WHERE clause in your sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

android app will not know when you have added/updated data in your table on the server until and unless you call script from app and fetch the data and update in your device.

only if your app has implemented these feature's

1. *push notification*- call Script every time you receive notification.
2. *XMPP service*- used for chat apps(which is not probably answer for
   your question right now)

here is my suggestion for you

**From server side:**

- create timestamp field in your table on server. update it with
  current timestamp value every time you do changes(i.e update/add) in
  the table.and when when that script is called send it across in json
  and make your app save it in sqlite along with data.
- server will compare for timestamp posted by app everytime with the
  saved timestamp in the server for new data.

**from client side:**

- for fist time timestamp from app will be 0. server will check it and
  send the whole data along with the timestamp saved during changes in
  table. save the data along with time stamp . second time when the
  script is called App will be sending the timestamp that was last
  saved.

with all this your app will not come to know still if new data is added until you call script and check. but atleast it will come to know if new data is received or not and whether to refresh ur screen

now comes script calling part from client side that is executing of assynch task, do it using handler to execute assynch class every minute

```
final Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable timerRunnable;


timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FetchRowNumAsync(context).execute(url);
                timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 60000); // run every minute
            }
        };
```

and unregister it in onDestroy()

```
@Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDestroyView();
            timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);

        }
```